# How to configure Camel HTTP4 Component to use NTLM Authentication

Tags: java, spring, http, ntlm

In Spring DSL, How can Camel's HTTP4 component be configured to use NTLM authentication?

I am able to configure Camel's HTTP component to use NTLM authentication, successfully, using this Spring DSL configuration:

```
<!-- Works: HTTP (3) Configuration -->
<bean id="httpConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpConfiguration">
    <property name="authMethod" value="NTLM"/>
    <property name="authHost" value="my-active-directory-host"/>
    <property name="authDomain" value="my-ad-domain"/>
    <property name="authUsername" value="my-username"/>
    <property name="authPassword" value="my-password"/>
</bean>

<!-- Works: HTTP (3) Component-->
<bean id="httpmw" class="org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpComponent">
    <property name="camelContext" ref="camel"/>
    <property name="httpConfiguration" ref="httpConfig"/>
</bean>
```

But, my best attempt to configure the HTTP4 component fails because I do not know how to set the httpClientConfiguration of the HttpComponent. Or perhaps, there is another way to wire the HTTP4 component?

```
<!-- Works: HTTP4 Configuration -->
<bean id="httpClientConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.http.NTLMAuthenticationHttpClientConfigurer">
    <constructor-arg name="proxy" value="false"/>
    <constructor-arg name="user" value="my-username"/>
    <constructor-arg name="pwd" value="my-password"/>
    <constructor-arg name="domain" value="my-ad-domain"/>
    <constructor-arg name="host" value="my-active-directory-host"/>
</bean>

<!-- Does not work: HTTP4 Component, exception
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: 
    Invalid property 'httpClientConfiguration' of bean class [org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpComponent]: 
    Bean property 'httpClientConfiguration' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. 
    Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
-->
<bean id="http4mw" class="org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpComponent">
    <property name="camelContext" ref="camel"/>
    <property name="httpClientConfiguration" ref="httpClientConfig"/>
</bean>
```